# How to serealize a list of type interface with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to get a list of different classes that share the same interface serealised. However, the following error appears:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: No parameterless constructor defined for 'StudentHousingFramework.Interfaces.IAccount'.

This is where the error occurs:

```
public void Serealise<T>(string nameList, List<T> list)
    {
        path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, nameList);
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        }); ;

        File.WriteAllText(path, jsonString);
    }
```

Here I'm trying to serialize, for example, a list of the class `rooms` that happen to have an interface called `IAccount`.

Here is that class:

```
    public class Room : IAccount
{
    public List<ITask> tasksToDo { 
        get
        {
            return factory.manager.tasks.FindAll(w => w.claimer == this);
        }
    }

    public Login login { get; set; }
    public bool isOccupied { get; private set; } = true;
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Room " + id;
        }
    }
    
    public Json json { get; set; } = new Json();
    private Factory factory { get; set; }

    public Room(Factory factory, int id)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.id = id;
        login = new Login();
    }


}
```

Here is the interface:

```
[JsonConverter (typeof(IAccount))]
public interface IAccount
{
    public Json json { get; set; }
    Login login { get; set; }
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get;}
}
```

Is there anything that I can do to salvage this situation?

Comment: You're trying to _deserialize_, and you can't do that into an interface. What class should Newtonsoft instantiate? It doesn't know. Deserialize into a `List<Room>`.

Comment: Let's say you're a serializer.  How would you go about doing that yourself?  If you don't have an implementation how would you know what to do?

Comment: The error is cast while serialization @CodeCaster. See edit for more info

Comment: @CitrusBoy, where exactly in the code you have shown us do you serialize anything?

Comment: @CodeCaster I posted the wrong thing m8. My bad entirely

Comment: I'm sorry to everyone, I posted by accident the wrong function. I edited it to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [JsonConverter(typeof(IAccount))]
> ```

That's not a valid converter type. Remove that.

NewtonSoft JSON is trying to instantiate `IAccount` as a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm), but it can't, as it's an interface (and doesn't inherit `JsonConverter`).

Comment: Then what should I do? Thanks for the feedback. I have removed them.

Comment: You should do nothing else. If you remove this, your serialization code will work.

Comment: Yeah It works but the derealisation method that I have doesn't work

Comment: Thx. I will be making another question for my new problem.

Comment: No, as I told you: you can't deserialize into an interface, and you shouldn't want to.

Comment: So what's the best way to go about it?

Comment: @CitrusBoy, CodeCaster already suggested to you how you could deserialize in their very 1st comment underneath your question above.